# how to open twitter popup window like facebook

Tags: javascript, share

```
$('.fbshare').on('click', function(){
    var url = window.location.href;
    window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + url,
        'facebook-share-dialog',
        'width=800,height=600'
    );
});
```

The above works fine and I want the same for twitter:

```
$('.twshare').on('click', function(){
    var url = window.location.href;
    window.open('https://twitter.com/share?url=' + url,
        'width=800,height=600'
    );
});
```

this opens a new tab instead a popup window

also on the new tab - inside the text box - the url has a space before

Comment: Is your browser possibly blocking the popup?

Comment: @sundaycode - of course not - facebook popup works

Comment: I figured it could possibly be a "trusted URL" of some sort. Trying in Chrome I'm presented with a blocked popup.

Comment: @sundaycode - blocked fb, tw or both?

Comment: Wait, after looking at your code again it looks like `window.open()` for Twitter is missing the second argument, the `windowName`. You have it in your FB example but not Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments, it looks like the second argument of [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), `windowName` was left out in your Twitter example. Try this:

```js
$('.twshare').on('click', function () {
    var url = window.location.href;
    window.open('https://twitter.com/share?url=' + url,
        'twitter-share-dialog',
        'width=800,height=600'
    );
});
```